# Selecting an item in the RadioButtonList, how to get a list of items to a ListBox from database in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `RadioButtonList` and a `ListBox`. I have bound `RadioButtonList` to database.
Therefore upon selecting an item in the `RadioButtonList`, I want to retrieve some data into the `ListBox`. The code I have tried is :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   RadioFill();
}

public void RadioFill()
    {
        SqlDataAdapter mydata = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT DISTINCT Param_Name FROM Parameter_Value_Master", con);
        DataSet dset = new DataSet();
        mydata.Fill(dset, "Table");
        RadioButtonList1.Items.Clear();
        RadioButtonList1.DataSource = dset.Tables[0];
        RadioButtonList1.DataTextField = dset.Tables[0].Columns["Param_Name"].ColumnName;
        RadioButtonList1.DataBind();
    }

protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
SqlDataAdapter mydata = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Value_Option FROM   Parameter_Value_Master", con);
DataSet dset = new DataSet();
mydata.Fill(dset, "Table");
ListBox1.Items.Clear();
ListBox1.DataSource = dset.Tables[0];
ListBox1.DataTextField = dset.Tables[0].Columns["Value_Option"].ColumnName;
ListBox1.DataBind();
}
```

The issue I am facing here is upon selecting an item, the whole panel in which I have placed both my `RadioButtonList` and `ListBox` goes invisible.

Kindly help...!! Thankyou...!!

Comment: can you show also how you defined your RadioButtonList1 and ListBox1 in your aspx page?

Comment: your code seems ok... can you show also the code with that panel? how those 2 items are defined in that panel? or they are created dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change Page_Load method as:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)¨
{
   if (!Page.IsPostBack)
   {
          RadioFill();
   }
}
```

If it not help than post code from your *.aspx file.

Remark: The method RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e),
there is not selecting based on radio button list selected value.